Class table inheritance (use or alternatives) on a BaaS webapp
I'm working on a personal project to keep track of the media I consume (movies, books, manga, anime, comics and series). Currently I'm in the process of modeling the database. As I was starting to understand the data and its relations, as well as going to 3NF, I came across this problem: all of these media types share a lot of common attributes and only have a couple of fields that distinguish them from each other. This UML diagram will make it clearer:

As you can probably tell by the diagram, I'm thinking of using class table inheritance over the alternative single table inheritance. So the questions are, is this approach any good? Are there any other better alternatives to solve this problem?
Something that might be relevant is that I'm planning to use PocketBase as my backend, so the database engine under the hood will be sqlite. Also, I know the amount of join operations to make any query on this model looks disgusting, I'm a noob when it comes to designing database models, so any suggestions on that regard are very welcome as well.

Technically, your diagram is a crowfoot notation, not UML. As for the design tips, you first build the normalised model (so the initial approach is correct) and then denormalise it to optimise for performance. I am no expert in this, thus just a comment instead of a full answer.

@Ister okay okay, i'm initially not too concerned with performance since this whole thing will basically be for personal use, but still, from your experience do you consider using a pattern like class table inheritance will make my database difficult to work with or hinder it on any meaningful way?

Like I said, I am no expert in designing. I am a business analyst, not aa architect or a developer and those are the people who take such decisions (based on my input).
